# is_container trait fails on std::set SFINAE issue

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, type-traits

I am trying to write a stream operator for std containers, mainly for the purpose of debugging.

I have the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <deque>


template<typename Container>
struct is_container
{
    typedef char no;
    typedef long yes;


    template<typename A, A, A>
    struct is_of_type;

    template<typename T>
            static yes& is_cont(
                            is_of_type
                            <
                                    typename T::iterator(T::*)(), 
                                    &T::begin,
                                    &T::end
                            >*);


    template<typename T>
    static no& is_cont(...);        //any other

    template<typename C, bool B>
    struct is_class_is_container
    {
            const static bool value=sizeof( is_cont<C>(nullptr) )==sizeof(yes);
    };

    template<typename C>
    struct is_class_is_container<C, false>
    {
            const static bool value=false;
    };

    const static bool value = is_class_is_container
            <
                    Container, 
                    std::is_class<Container>::value 
            >::value;
};

template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if
    < is_container<T>::value, std::ostream >::type& 
    operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& a)
{
    os << '[';
    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::ostream_iterator<typename T::value_type>(os, ", "));
    os << ']';
    return os;
}
```

I am aware this is far from perfect (constructive comments appreciated) but the problem I am having is that it works great for vector, deque and list but fails to match on sets, I don't know why because sets still have the iterator interfaces begin and end.

Thanks.

EDIT:  tested on
g++ (GCC) 4.6.2 2012012 
clang version 3.0

EDIT2: I got it sort of working using decltype however that is sub optimal because now I can't assert that it does what I expect (return an iterator) to.

I don't exactly know what the set was return in the first place, maybe if someone has a way of debugging TMP that would be good.

Comment: I have some form of `is_container` trait in the [pretty printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers), if you're interested.

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks, I will look over that, however as this is really a test of me getting something like this working I would like to do exactly that and try and get it to work.

Comment: This looks unnecessary involved. Try this: http://ideone.com/gBx6P

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: yep that is much better still, I wasn't aware you could do inheritance with the type_traits it is much cleaner. I just need to stop it to binding cases where an operator is already defined.

Comment: Maybe that is because `std::set` is not a container in the usual sense. (it violates certain properties that you expect from a container.) Maybe `std::set` is something like a immutable-container (elements cannot be modified).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `std::set<T>` only has one set of immutable iterators, there is only one version of `begin()` and `end()` which is declared to be `const`. That is, the definition of `std::set<T>` looks something like this (assuming it was declared in namespace `std` before):

```
template <typename T>
class std::set
{
public:
    class            iterator;
    typedef iterator const_iterator;
    ...
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;
    ...
};
```

The other containers have both a `const` and a non-`const` version of `begin()` and `end()` matching the signature you ask for. `std::set` doesn't have this. I'm not sure what the easiest work-around for this would be though.

That said, `sizeof(char)` is allowed to be `sizeof(long)`. The easiest way to guarantee that the `yes` and `no` types have different size is to use references to arrays of different sizes for the same type, e.g.:

```
typedef char (&yes)[1];
typedef char (&no)[2];
...
enum { value = sizeof(some_expression) == sizeof(yes) };
```

Comment: I was close then, I tried the array thing, but didn't realise it had to be a reference. That is better. Also I was unware that set only had const iterators. I guess I was thrown by this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin oh well it works now. I don't really think I will bother with the enum bit I am targeting c++11 so I don't thing vc6.0 quirks are a good enough reason to obfuscate my code. Anyway Thanks again.

Comment: Well, the `enum` bit isn't so much a quirk for "VC6.0" but a necessity if you ever end up passing the value to something which needs the definition of the value, e.g. a function taking it by `const&`: your `static bool const value = ...` is still **not** a definition although it is given an initial value! If you are using C++2011 you can also define (not just initialize) the value in the class definition by using `static bool constexpr value = ...` (although I'm not entirely sure where the `constexpr` qualify can go, i.e. this notation may be slightly wrong).

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, I can rip out yes/no for consexpr

Comment: @Dietmar are you saying that `static bool constexpr value = ...` in the class definition is a definition instead of only a declaration? That would be new to me. Where can I read about it?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: no, I'm not saying that `constexpr` in the class definition is a definition. It is still a declaration. However, my understanding is that binding this value to a `const&` doesn't require a definition to be available while doing the same with a `static T const` initialized in the class definition does require a definition to be available.

Answer (score 2):

It works for `vector` but not for `set` because the latter returns `const_iterator` for `begin`/`end` functions. Change:

```
typename T::iterator(T::*)(),
```

to:

```
typename T::const_iterator(T::*)() const,
```